# Ajax is not working in Django?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

**Ajax code:**

```
$(".addtofavourite").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var bid = $(this).attr('id'); //integer value
    var email = $("#userEmail").val();
    alert(bid + " " + email);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/userfavourite/",
        data: {
            'BID': bid,
            'EmailID': email
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }

    });
});
```

**Views.py :**

```
def userfavourite(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['EmailID']
        bid = request.POST['BID']
        uid = UserInfo.objects.values("UID").filter(email__exact=email)
        userfav = UserFavourite.objects.filter(UID=uid, BID=bid)
        if not (userfav):
            userfav = UserFavourite(UID=uid, BID=bid)
            userfav.save()
            data = serializers.serialize("json", "True")
            return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')

        else:
             data = serializers.serialize("json", "False")
             return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
    else:
        data = serializers.serialize("json", "False")
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Idon't Know why Ajax always return error in alert.What is error in my code? I want to get from view true or false in return and want to print on screen.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in alert?

Comment: It simply print "error" in alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, as a security measure, django uses CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) Tokens to screen all POST requests.
There are two options there:

1. The best option is to add the CSRF Token in the request (you can find it either by reading the cookie information or serving in a template)
2. If it isn't possible, use the csrf_exempt decorator to deactivate it in your Ajax view (less secure)

Both methods are explained in detail at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/